# PHP - How to get all rows from a MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code:

```
if($login_check > 0) {
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messageInfo WHERE senderUsername='$username' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM messageInfo WHERE recieverUsername='$username';");
    var_dump(mysql_fetch_assoc($results));

}
```

I'm getting only one row "var_dumped", when I should be getting two rows returned.

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: Also, please refrain from drastically rewriting a question as to make it entirely different.  You have basically invalidated a set of previously given answers and wasted a great deal of time.  It's poor form at best, and editors crankier than myself may choose to revert your massive rewrite.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try following code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messageInfo WHERE senderUsername='$username' OR recieverUsername='$username'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

I think that `UNION` is not really needed in this query, `OR` statement would be just enough.

Comment: thank you sir! You have solved an hours work. The reason ours wasn't working was because var_dump stopped the PHP script. I feel stupid

Answer (score 0):

```
  $sqlriz = "Select * FROM `tablename`";


    $Rslt = mysqli_query($Conn,$sqlriz);

    while($r=mysqli_fetch_object($Rslt))
    {
        $res[]=$r;
    }

print_r($res);
```

Comment: Can you try and enhance the formatting and add some explanation what the key points are?